# .NET Core IQueryable Lambda Memory Leak

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, lambda, memory-leaks

I am using a lambda query as below on a column with a Unique index in the table. For each request, approximately 8 -12 kb memory leak occurs.

This method will be called approximately 10-20 times per second.

```
bool KontrolKullanildi(string QrCode)
{
    using (EmlesCore.Models.Database db = new EmlesCore.Models.Database())
    {                
        using (var o = db.mobilQrTempler.AsNoTracking().Where(f => f.CryptoKod == QrCode && f.Kullanildi).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault())
        {
            if (o != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: Memory status]

[image: Code]

I know I use `AsNoTracking` in different places. I made experiments.

A friend said, "The database connection process may be in progress, so dispose won't work".

This made so much sense. I've tried `.ToList()`, I've tried `Count()`, but nothing has worked.

8-10 kb may seem small. But as I said, when the number of requests is high, the memory used in IIS can be 2 GB in 1-2 hours.

Database Model is DbContext class. and mobileQrTempler is table.
I also didn't want to create another model. Actually, I wanted to prevent possible memory leak by pulling data directly from dbcontext. But again it didn't. By the way, I call this method in view with Jquery Ajax. So actually this method is inside a controller. Not apicontroller. A question comes to my mind, is there an overload on the controller?
Is the controller not suitable to be called too many times ?
Could it be that too many requests are causing memory to accumulate on the controller?
I know you said "No problem with lambda query". I don't think so. But Somewhere there is a problem. I'll try another test. I want to try it with 1000 RPS by adding this method by making a rest api.

```
public class Database:DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Utils.DbConnectionString());
        
    }

public DbSet<mobileQrTemp> mobilQrTempler { get; set; }
```

}

**Controller**

```
public class QrGirisCikisQrKontrol : Controller{
public async Task<JsonResult> GetQrCode(string parameters)
    {
    if (KontrolKullanildi(QrFiltre))
        {
            return Json(QrCodeOlusturDondur(Parameters));
        }

    return Json(Ok());
}
```

}

Sample Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetQrCode","QrGirisCikisQrKontrol")",
        data: params,
        success: function (result) ..............
```

Jquery Ajax calls this method once every 4.5 seconds. This system is installed on about 100 clients at the moment. When I look at the log records of the server, I see that there are approximately 7-8 requests per second.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it a memory leak. In .NET (like many managed language), the garbage collector clean the object instance when it's necessary. Try do more request and you will see the memory usage stabilize.

If you want check if the web application has a memory leak when a controller's action is called, you can try to add a middleware that force the garbage collector to do the cleaning :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
var app = builder.Build();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next(context);
    Sytem.GC.Collect();
});
...
app.Run();
```

Think to remove this before to deploy the application, because it isn't recommended to call manually the garbage collector. But it can be a quick temporary fix when a bad coded application has a abnormal memory usage.

---

Moreover, a ASP.NET Core application run by default in garbage collector server mode. In this mode, the garbage collector work less and the cleaning is rarely done.

Other effect of this mode, the memory allocate by the application is never released. On server, the number of process and memory is fixed. It's a waste of time to release the memory to reallocate it later, then the application keep the memory allocated. More information in :

- [Runtime configuration options for garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector)
- [Memory management and garbage collection (GC) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory)

You can disable this behavior by adding in in `app.config` (or `web.config`) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It's recommended when a web application has a memory usage varying.

---

Off topic, you can optimize the EF query by :

```cs
bool KontrolKullanildi(string QrCode)
{
    using (EmlesCore.Models.Database db = new EmlesCore.Models.Database())
    {
        return db.mobilQrTempler.Any(f => f.CryptoKod == QrCode && f.Kullanildi);
    }
}
```

Then the query will be like :

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM mobilQrTempler
WHERE CryptoKod = @QrCode AND Kullanildi = 1
```

and EF Core will load just one boolean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. GC.Collect is a method that I do not prefer to use. However, after 1 - 1.5 hours, the IIS Worker Process Memory value reaches around 1,161.2 MB. Clients call this method 7-8 times per second. I can't find a reason for this memory buildup. Using, dispose, Gc.Collect none of them were a solution.
There is no problem when I exit with the Return value before the Database lambda query in the Method. But from the moment I call the Lambda query this problem starts.

Comment: ~1 Go, it's big. I can assure you that this method is not the problem.  Do you try to disable the server mode?

Comment: GC.Collect is also helpful quick-and-dirty diagnostic. If memory grows despite GC.Collect you're more likely to have a genuine leak, rather than just generating a lot of garbage.

Comment: @vernou Thank you. Yes I tried now. I tested with 8 request submissions per second.
I added the following block for .net Core to the project file.
<ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>

It kept coming up to 760 mb for the 5000th request.

In the original state, it is 760 mb on the 1000th request. it's coming.

It actually saved time. However, it continues to increase. And I'm having trouble understanding why it's increasing.

Comment: Can you show the `mobileQrTemp` class? I suspect this class, because it implement `IDisposable`.